# Flutter permanently hide bottom android navigation bar (status bar)

Tags: android, flutter, dart, bottomnavigationview, flutter-bottomnavigation

I'm trying to hide my android default navigation bar. I'm using `SystemChrome` on my `main.dart` :

```
void main() async {
  SystemChrome.setEnabledSystemUIOverlays([SystemUiOverlay.top]);
  ...
```

But whenever I'm touching my screen the navigation bar appears again.

On the other hand, when I'm hiding both top and bottom using:

```
void main() async {
  SystemChrome.setEnabledSystemUIOverlays([]);
  ...
```

They are both **permanently** remove.

I need to remove **only** the bottom navigation bar. What is the problem? How can I fix that?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try using `SystemChrome.setEnabledSystemUIMode` instead of `SystemChrome.setEnabledSystemUIOverlays`

example:

```
SystemChrome.setEnabledSystemUIMode(
  SystemUiMode.manual,
  overlays: [SystemUiOverlay.top],
);
```